# Is there a way to open an editor app in ios and receive edited results?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have an app that downloads files from a web server.  Our customer wants the ability to edit those files on their mobile devices and upload the edited version to our servers.  Is this possible in iOS?  I have figured out how to allow users to view the files in external apps, but I don't see a way to bring back their changes if the file was modified as it seems to copy the file into the other app's space, so my app is left with the unaltered version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS has a sandbox mechanism, so for sure you can not modify any file in another app.

The only way to transfer data from different app is using sharing.

This is a sample project I wrote for implement sharing on iOS, check it:

[Sample for sharing on iOS](https://github.com/lwnwowone/SharingImplement)

Hope it can help you.

Comment: But if I have no control over the app that I'm sharing with then, that app cannot return the file to my app when it's done?

Comment: Unfortunately, if the app you can't control the app you are sharing, you can not get any feedback, you just can give them an entrance to control your app using the "OpenUrl" method in your AppDelegate.cs, like FaceBook share SDK.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I will just have to tell the client that the functionality that they are looking for is not supported in iOS.